How to color these textblocks?
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}%schaltet Silbentrennung aus
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% für \justifying
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{LightGray}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229897/simplest-way-to-get-a-colored-rectangle-behind-text
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
 \par\noindent
 \colorbox{gray!30}{%
 \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
 #1
 }%
 }}

\begin{document}

\highlight{\lipsum*[1]}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229897/simplest-way-to-get-a-colored-rectangle-behind-text
\colorbox[gray]{0.5}{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{The fundamental......}}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210555/how-do-you-make-text-flow-to-another-part-of-a-page

%1. box

\setbox0\vbox{\hsize=5cm\justifying %\raggedright %Ausrichtung und Breite

\noindent „Er ist verrückt“, dachte sich der kleine Jan, der im Treppenhaus des Mehrfamilienhauses saß, in dem er mit seinen Eltern wohnte und den Kater der Nachbarin streichelte. „Herr Veith ist alt und verrückt“. Seine Tür stand immer einen Spalt weit offen, egal ob bei Tag oder Nacht, und man hörte ihn wirres Zeug flüstern. Wenn es so leise war wie jetzt, glaubte man, die Worte entschlüsseln zu können, die er brabbelte. Doch so sehr man sich auch darauf konzentrierte, es war unmöglich, den Sinn dieses Kauderwelschs zu entziffern. Jan fuhr Felix, dem Kater, in gleichmäßigen Zügen über den Rücken. Mit der anderen Hand stützte er seinen Kopf und starrte durch das große Fenster hinunter in den dunklen Hof vor dem Haus, der gerade von einem heftigen Sommerregen überschwemmt wurde. 
}

%2. box
\setbox1\vsplit0 to 3cm %height of textbox

%3. box
\setbox2\vsplit0 to 4cm

%4. box
\setbox3\vsplit0 to 4cm

\setlength{\fboxrule}{.5pt}% %frame around box
\fbox{\begin{picture}(350,400)

\put(10,200){{\rotatebox{45}{\box1}}}
\put(230,260){{\rotatebox{-45}{\box2}}}
\put(200,10){{\rotatebox{20}{\box0}}}
\put(0,60){{\rotatebox{-15}{\box3}}}

\end{picture}}

\end{document}


In the question How do you make text flow to another part of a page? @DavidCarlisle provided a neat solution for the separation of text into several textblocks (Thanks and all credits to @DavidCarlisle). I took this idea in order to create a "non typical" layout (see source code).
Everything works very nice as long as I don´t try to add color which is what I would like to do. I tried to apply the predefined commands "\highlight" as well as "\colorbox{...}" (see source code), e.g. \colorbox[gray]{0.5}{\setbox1\vsplit0 to 3cm} to the textbox but instead of coloring the textbox (which is what I like to do) the whole text dissapaers.
How can I apply some color to the background of the four separated text snippets? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Well, you can't wrap the \vsplit in a colorbox: the assignment is lost in the group. What you want is \rotatebox{45}{\colorbox{...}{...}}.

@campe: Do I understand it right that I have to use four different textboxes/colorboxes each with its own text snippet if I like to colorize the textbox, i.e. the text flow from frame to frame is  not possible? If this is the case I will use individual textboxes. Thank you.
